# With Windows Azure, can I deploy a node.js server using Dropbox?

Tags: node.js, azure, dropbox

There are several [tutorials](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-%28mac%29/) on Azure showing how to deploy a node.js server using git. Azure has a nifty feature where you can link a Dropbox folder to an Azure web site for very simple deployments. Works awesome for websites, but I was hoping it might work for node.js deployments as well.

It doesn't seem to work- the deployment process goes fine, but navigating to the URL of the node.js deployment produces this error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Anyone know if it's possible to  deploy a node.js server to Windows Azure via Dropbox?

Many thanks-

**UPDATE-**
Just ran through the deployment logs and found this line:

```
The package.json file is not present.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.6.20.
```

Perhaps that it explains my problem?

Comment: most node.js providers won't run an app if you're missing a package.json file. here's a good page to get you started: http://package.json.nodejitsu.com. Also regarding the version, there's a specific parameter/key called engines in package.json, make sure this either 0.8.x (previous stable) or 0.10.x (stable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the console and folder type "npm init" to generate package.json